# Wrap every element of variadic parameter pack in a wrapper and store in std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++17, stdtuple

Consider two classes:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};
```

And a class:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct packed {
   using Tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;
   Tuple tpl;
};
```

and

```
template<typename T>
struct wrapper {
T t;
};
```

What I would like is instead of `Tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>` inside of `packed` but rather a tuple whose every element is like `using WrappedTuple = std::tuple<wrapper<T0>, wrapper<T1>, ..., wrapper<TN-1>>;`

The goal being to enhance each of the given types by a common set of attributes.

Comment: So... what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? How are the classes you show supposed to be used? Please try to create a [mcve] of how you want to use these classes, and tell us the problems you have with it. And please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

Just expand `wrapper<Ts>` with `...`.  This produces a template parameter pack where each element is `wrapper<T>`, `T` being each respective type in the `Ts` pack.

```
using Tuple = std::tuple<wrapper<Ts>...>;
```

([Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29b5eba2daaa2f35))